# Python print element happens after the next element

Tags: python, python-3.x, morse-code

I'm trying to make a text-to-morse translator with Python (using Python 3.8 in vs code) But there's a problem in line running order. This is my code(question is after the code):

```
import winsound
import time


def beep(char):
    sound = {
        '-': 500, 
        '.': 150, 
    }
    for dashdot in item_dict[char]:
        winsound.Beep(500, sound[dashdot])
        time.sleep(.05)


item_dict = {
    'a': '.-',
    'b': '-...',
    'c': '-.-.',
    'd': '-..',
    'e': '.',
    'f': '..-.',
    'g': '--.',
    'h': '....',
    'i': '..',
    'j': '.---',
    'k': '-.-',
    'l': '.-..',
    'm': '--',
    'n': '-.',
    'o': '---',
    'p': '.--.',
    'q': '--.-',
    'r': '.-.',
    's': '...',
    't': '-',
    'u': '..-',
    'v': '...-',
    'w': '.--',
    'x': '-..-',
    'y': '-.--',
    'z': '--..',
    '0': '-----',
    '1': '.----',
    '2': '..---',
    '3': '...--',
    '4': '....-',
    '5': '.....',
    '6': '-....',
    '7': '--...',
    '8': '---..',
    '9': '----.',
    '.': '.-.-.-',
    ',': '--..--',
    '?': '..--..',
    '-': '-...-',
    '/': '-..-.'
}


def morse():
    x = input("?\n")
    name_list = list(x)
    for x in name_list:
        print(item_dict[f"{x}"], end=' ')
        beep(x)
        time.sleep(.5)
    morse()


print('''text to morse-text
    enter the text you want''')


morse()
```

as you can see in this part:

```
  for x in name_list:
        print(item_dict[f"{x}"], end=' ')
        beep(x)
        time.sleep(.5)
```

The element `print` is before the function `beep`. So it should first print and then make the noise. But it makes the noises and then, after making noise for all chars, prints the codes. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error description. Each sound coincides with the printing of each morse code letter. Nice application.

Comment: Thanks, maybe it's there's a problem with vs code terminal but still, it makes all the sounds and prints the words all together afterward. @Mr.T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `flush=True` to your `print` statement like so:

```
print(item_dict[f"{x}"], end=' ', flush=True)
```

This forces the output on the console. This is useful in your case, when you specify a custom "end of the line" argument. When it's not a newline, it doesn't get automatically printed as is.

Comment: This only works past Python version 3.3 by the way: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: I'm using python 3.8 as I said.

Comment: I wrote it as a heads-up to anyone else possibly having the same issue. Glad it helped!

Answer (score -1):

Im not quite sure I understand your question fully, but your program currently
first prints the morse value of a letter to the console, and next makes the corresponding sound. So if that is what you wanted, you don't have to change anything.

Otherwise if you want to print the morse for the whole sentence, and after that make all the corresponding sounds, you can just use two loops:

```py
def morse():
    x = input("?\n")
    for char in x:
        print(item_dict[char], end=' ')
    for char in x:
        beep(char)
        time.sleep(.5)
    morse()
```

instead of making a list of the string input like:

```py
name_list = list(x)
for x in name_list:
```

you can just past the input string in the for loop, it will automatically loop over every character in your string:

```py
for char in x:
```

where `x` is your input string

Comment: Know about string, And I want to print them by order, Not the hole sentence. But it seems I should change something because it first makes all the noises and then prints the words all together. Totally confused.